# Unity не показывает очертание невидимых обхектов

Tags: unity3d

Что-то понять не могу, вот я создал Canvas, но при его выделении, я не вижу его размеров в сцене, хотя он не 0 размера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так же при выделении камеры я не вижу иконки камеры:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя на ютубе в гайдах я вижу, что у людей все отображается.

Comment: включите "Gizmos"

Comment: Заработало. Сап